# Solving system of equations using Sympy on GPU

Tags: python, gpu, sympy, gaussian, symbolic-math

I am currently solving the following problem (Gaussian tail approximation) using solve() :

```py
x, y = symbols('x y')
l_bound = np.mean(self.data[j]) - 3 * np.std(self.data[j])  # e.g. 4
u_bound = np.mean(self.data[j]) + 3 * np.std(self.data[j])  # e.g. 13
sol_dict = solve([y/(x-1) - 3 * y/sqrt(((x-1)**2)*(x-2))-l_bound, y/(x-1) + 3 * y/sqrt(((x-1)**2) * (x-2))-u_bound], [x, y], dict=True)
```

I am trying to find a way to speed up the process, because it takes forever and I have quite many rows of a matrix of data to process (each j is a row).
The examples I found in the [documentaries](https://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/numeric-computation.html) show how to evaluate a function - Is there a possibility to use solve() on GPU?

What I've done so far: I've read through documentaries, unable to find the right expression. - As I am new to the topic, I might have missed some essential part (sorry if my question might be trivial). Thanks in advance for any pointer in a more suited direction, appreciate any help.

Comment: No you can't. That "Numeric Computation" section is for optimizing the evaluation of a symbolic expression. Anyway, your equations are simple and you can solve them analytically. Why not do that? I got ```x = 2 + 9 * ((u+l)/(u-l))^2, y = ((u+l)/2) * (x-1)```, but didn't check.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sympy is a CAS based purely on Python, so I don't believe that complex computations such a solvers can easily be ported to work on a GPU.

However, by looking at your example it appears that you are trying to get numerical solutions. Hence, `solve` is not the right tool for the job. `nsolve` (numerical solve) might be better suited for the job. Generally, you will need to provide appropriate initial guesses. For example:

```py
l_bound = 4
u_bound = 13
expr1 = y/(x-1) - 3 * y/sqrt(((x-1)**2)*(x-2))-l_bound
expr2 = y/(x-1) + 3 * y/sqrt(((x-1)**2) * (x-2))-u_bound
nsolve([expr1, expr2], [x, y], [10, 10])
# out: (34.1111111111111, 281.444444444444)
```

You'll notice that for this particular case, `nsolve` is much faster than `solve`. However, for each iteration of your loop, `nsolve` will convert the system of symbolic equations to a system of numerical functions using `lambdify`: this operation is expensive. If the form of your equations is not changing with iterations, than we can convert the system of symbolic equations to a system of numerical functions once, at the beginning, and reuse that inside the loop with updated values. For example:

```py
from mpmath import findroot

l_bound, u_bound = symbols("l u")
expr1 = y/(x-1) - 3 * y/sqrt(((x-1)**2)*(x-2))-l_bound
expr2 = y/(x-1) + 3 * y/sqrt(((x-1)**2) * (x-2))-u_bound

system = Matrix([expr1, expr2]).T
J = system.jacobian([x, y])
# convert symbolic objects to numerical functions
system = lambdify([x, y, l_bound, u_bound], system.T, modules="mpmath")
J = lambdify([x, y, l_bound, u_bound], J, modules="mpmath")

l_bounds, u_bounds = [4], [13]
IG = [10, 10]
for l, u in zip(l_bounds, u_bounds):
    # provide new values of lower and upper bounds with each iteration
    sol = findroot(lambda x, y: system(x, y, l, u), IG, J=lambda x, y: J(x, y, l, u))
    # continue your task
```

Notes:

1. sympy's `nsolve` is going to do exactly what we have done in the previous code block: convert the system of equations to a symbolic matrix, compute a symbolic jacobian, converts both system and Jacobian to numerical functions and use mpmath's `findroot` to find the solution.
2. Maybe it's possible to further improve the performance if instead of using mpmath's `findroot` you use some other root finding algorithm from Scipy. That's for you to find out :)

Comment: Thank you! - That answers quite many questions!